# Login on HTTPS website with java

Tags: java, authentication

I'm trying to build a Java program, that automatically logs in into a website using https protocol. I just want to input my name and password into my prog, hit submit and get the page that would appear, if i did that in browser.

I already wrote a program that shows the html code of the site using SSLSocket class.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class bankpost{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final String page = "banking.postbank.de";
    SSLSocketFactory sf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    try {
        SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(page, 443);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

        System.out.println("Sending request to server "
                + s.getInetAddress());
        out.print("POST /rai/login HTTP1.1\r\n\r\n");
        String content = "nutzername=a&kennwort=a";
        String cmd = "POST /rai/login HTTP/1.1\n"
                + "Host: banking.postbank.de\n"
                + "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n"
                + "Content-Length: " + content.length() + "\n\n"
                + content + "\r\n\r\n";
        out.print(cmd);
        out.flush();
        in.useDelimiter(">");
        System.out.println("Reading...");
        int len = 0;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.next();
            len += line.length();
            if (line.contains("field-input") || line.contains("nicht"))
                System.err.println(line.trim());
            else
                System.out.println(line.trim());
        }

        System.out.println("DONE - " + len);
        System.out.print(cmd);
        in.close();
        out.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

...the fields I want to put input to are "nutzername" and "kennwort".

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I've no idea what you're doing wrong as you did not tell us what happened after you executed this code. Can you provide any details like a stacktrace?

Comment: oh yeah sry :S nutzername=a kennwort=a is not a valid login. if i do that in browser, is message is displayed, that password is wrong. but my programm doesnt print that message, but the exact same text like if i replace "post" with "get"..

Comment: If that worked Postbank would have done a very bad job.

Comment: @Lucas: Wow.  Now that is some seriously messed up bank if you can use a software to automatically log on to your "online banking" accounts.  **ALL** of my bank accounts, at four different banks, do not allow automated login.  Three of them use a physical cryptographic device and require a challenge/response to be able to log in (and individual challenge/response when wiring big amounts too).  The fourth one display a (kinda lame) area where the numbers from 0 to 9 are shuffled inside a rectangle and you need to enter your PIN using the mouse (this could be OCR'ed but still).

Comment: @Lucas: I'll make sure to avoid any bank allowing to do what you're doing like the plague ; )

Comment: actually the bank was just an example.

Comment: Just 'sniff' the request using your favorite browser and a corresponding plugin, e.g. Firebug or Webkit's built-in facilities. Btw: The parameters 'nutzername' and 'kennwort' exactly match those defined on `banking.postbank.de`. Bad example!

Answer (score 0):

I would try some standard HttpsConnection magic. SSL needs certificates and trust managers to be set properly. Initialize HttpsContext like this:

```
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    // here you may want to call sc.init() with your key managers and trustmanagers 
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(verifier);
    HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

    //setting authenticator which will push your credentials to the server when required
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(config.getUserName(), config.getPassword().toCharArray());
        }
    })
```

where the verifier is a descentant class implementing HostnameVerifier interface and accepts the site url that you are working with.

After context is all set you just work with new URL().getConnection() as for any other simple http sites.

Comment: is there no different way without using HttpsURLConnection?